# Question on plural

Tags: grammatical-number

Say there are two universities and each has a faculty of medicine.  So when I refer to the two faculties, do I say -

(a) The facult**ies** of medicine of the two universities; or

(b) The facult**y** of medicine of the two universities?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This question may be asked on [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

I choose (a) faculties of medicine in the two Universities.
You are writing of two different faculties from two different Universities.